# Angularjs ng-class with ng-grid / swapping css style

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ng-class

I have this very simple angular app using ng-grid. I for some reason don't know how to apply style based on data. I need to be able to display different status image based on data status Code below:

controller:

```
$scope.myData2 = [
            {service: "aaa", status: "ok"},
            {service: "ccc", status: "warning"}];
$scope.gridOptions2 = {
            data: 'myData2',
            headerRowHeight:0,
            rowHeight: 39,
            enableRowSelection: false,
            enableHighlighting:true,
            columnDefs: [
                {field: 'service', enableCellEdit: true},
                {field:'status', cellTemplate : 'stateTemplate.html'}]
        };
```

directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive("statusIcon", function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<div ng-class=status-{{row.getProperty('status')}}></div>"
        };
    });
```

template:

```
<status-icon></status-icon>
```

css:

```
.status-ok{
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url("../images/status_ok.png") no-repeat;

}

.status-warning{
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url("../images/status_ok.png") no-repeat;

}
```

when I render the page this is the output:

```
<status-icon class="ng-scope"><div ng-class="status-ok"></div></status-icon>
```

I'm missing a classic `class="status-ok"`

What am I doing wrong?

PLUNKR http://plnkr.co/edit/4xTC4pKIR0AnzD89iIp2?p=preview

Comment: you can use cell template.

Comment: any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at cell templating [article here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating).

```
columnDefs: [{ field: 'firstName', displayName: 'First Name', width: 90, cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div>' },
                     { field: 'lastName', displayName: 'Last Name', width: 80 },
                     { field: 'age', cellClass: 'ageCell', headerClass: 'ageHeader' } ]
```

you can define `cellClass` or `headerClass` or completely different `cellTemplate`

**EDIT**

below is example on how to use ng-class with cell template

```
<div ng-class="row.entity[col.field] == 'success' ? 'successClass' : 'errorClass'">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div>
```

**EDIT**

working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsq17Y4lCPauFiPvDptD?p=preview)

you dont need ng-class you just need class

Comment: that doesn't work for me. How can I pick the ng-class and assign it to the normal class?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but your solution does not work. And I'm getting errors. I just simply need to assign ng-class value into normal class if it cannot be achieved with cellTemplate

Comment: sure, give me a few mins

Comment: check the fix, though i havent used the directive, you can easily replace my template with your directive